# How to create editable parameter based on conditions of another parameter?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

For Jenkins pipeline, I've a parameter say `Repository` and second parameter say `Branch`.

Based on `Repository` value, I want to auto-populate, value for `Branch`.

Let's say -

if `Repository` is `BobRepo` then for `Branch` value `BobBranch` is auto populated

if `Repository` is `AdamRepo` then for `Branch` value `AdamBranch` is auto populated

This can be achieved using `Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter`.

But if user provides, some unknown value to `Repository` like `UnknownRepo` then he should be allowed to type in value in `Branch` parameter which is not possible with `Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter`

Can you please help how to achieve editable parameter when conditions don't match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can achieve that using the `Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter`.
All you need is to set the `Branch` parameter to be of *Choice Type* **Formatted HTML** and use the following template that is provided in the [official documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/):

```
return "<input name=\"value\" value=\"${ReactiveRefParam}\" class=\"setting-input\" type=\"text\">"
```

This code template will create an input parameter with the propagated value that was defined in the `value` attribute ,and it enables the user to edit the propagated value.
In your case it will look something like:

```groovy
def branch = ''
if (Repository == 'BobRepo') {
   branch = 'BobBranch'
} else if (Repository == 'AdamRepo') {
   branch = 'AdamBranch'
}
return "<input name='value' value='${branch}' class='setting-input' type='text'>"
```

If you want the input field to be read only on certain values, then it is also possible using the `readonly` attribute of the HTML input with some logic.
In addition you can also add HTML styles to input as you wish.
Here is an example that prevents edits when a branch is populated and the input width is changed to a custom value:

```groovy
def branch = ''
if (Repository == 'BobRepo') {
   branch = 'BobBranch'
} else if (Repository == 'AdamRepo') {
   branch = 'AdamBranch'
}
return "<input name='value' value='${Repository}' style='width: 200px;' class='setting-input' type='text' ${branch ? 'readonly' : ''}>"
```